# URL структура файловой системы сайта

Tags: url

Готовлю к релизу сайт. Сайт пока что не планируется натягивать на CMS.
Структура:

```
-css
-fonts
-icons
-img
-js
-page-elements
-uslugi (страница)
  -usluga-1 (страница)
  -usluga-2 (страница)
  -usluga-3 (страница)
-index.html
```

Сейчас при открытии страницы "uslugi" url выглядит так:
`https://site.ru/uslugi/uslugi.html`

Сначала встал вопрос как убрать на конце ".html" - тут решение нашел.

Но я не понимаю как добиться того, что бы при открытии страницы "uslugi" url имел вид:
`https://site.ru/uslugi/`

Comment: Начать с чтения документации используемого вами веб-сервера

Comment: Вы придумали какую-то ерунду... сайт состоит из одной лишь статики? если ответ нет - ваш вариант ну прям очень плох. И у вас не сайт, а шаблон, судя по всему) Если хочется развиваться - посмотрите в сторону фрейверков) ларавел/симфони.. они ЗАСТАВЯТ вас кодить "правильно"

Comment: если на апаче, почитайте про .htaccess в целом и mod_rewrite в часности

Comment: всем спасибо за советы и мнение